# Stop cordova plugin fetch over the internet

Tags: netbeans, cordova

I use netbeans 7.4 with cordova. I am developing cross platform application using cordova (html+js).

my problem is that everytime I want to deploy the application into mobile, cordova seems to update plugins from the internet. The same issue when I add a plugin or during the new project wizard.

Is there is a way to disable internet fetching and let them be done only once.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem. We need to comment the **update-plugins** task on ANT file. It is on **<project>/nbproject/build.xml**

You must to execute one time, after you could comment.

More information at: [http://francisco.pro/2014/09/construindo-aplicativos-off-line-no-netbeans-8-0/](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=pt&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Ffrancisco.pro%2F2014%2F09%2Fconstruindo-aplicativos-off-line-no-netbeans-8-0%2F&edit-text=&act=url)